# Nexus not returning the right content

Tags: nexus

We have a nexus server where we have a yum repository. I have weird issue. When we try to see the repomd.xml file through the DNS name, it shows outdated content. If we hit it directly through the ELB (AWS) we get the fresh content, .

The last modified date is different on the first request on both these requests.

Is there any setting in nexus to fix this behavior?

Comment: Nexus doesn't change what it delivers based on what is asking for it.  It sounds like something outside of Nexus is caching?  Is there a squid proxy in use, for example?

Comment: As Rich is pointing out, this is likely not a Nexus Repository issue, and something else in the middle caching a request. I would take a look whatever is sitting in front of Nexus Repository that might be causing this.

Comment: We resolved the issue, like you guys said it was not a Nexus issue. We had forcepoint installed on the office network. It was caching the request. We added rule to exclude the domain and it is working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the issue. We had forcepoint installed on the office network. It was caching the request. We added rule to exclude the domain and it is working fine now